# How to actually apply ROS2 to real robot?

Tags: ros2, ros-humble

i have read and run the simulation on turtlebot3. Now i want how to do it with the real simple robot car, just forward, back and turn. I know it can be done easily with raspberry pi and wiringPi library. Please tell me how to do it with rclcpp. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Wildfeat, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided does not directly deal with the implementation of the robot's movement, but rather describes your effort to transfer the simulation to a real robot car.

To use rclcpp (Robotics Client Library for C++), you need to install ROS 2 (Robot Operating System 2) on the Raspberry Pi. ROS 2 is an open-source framework for developing robotic applications. After installing ROS 2, you can start working with rclcpp.

Rclcpp is a C++ library that provides an interface for communicating with the ROS 2 system and managing nodes and topics. To control a real robot car using rclcpp, you'll need to write a program to communicate with the car's hardware (eg motors to move forward and backward, sensors to detect obstacles, etc.).

Here is an example of simple C++ code that shows how to use rclcpp to control the forward, backward, and rotation of the robot:

```cpp
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  auto node = rclcpp::Node::make_shared("robot_control");

  // Forward, backward and rotation commands
  // ...

  rclcpp::spin(node);
  rclcpp::shutdown();

  return 0;
}
```

In this example, a ROS node named "robot_control" is created. Node initializes rclcpp and then uses the `spin` function to run the node. In this function, you can implement commands to control the movement of the robot forward, backward and rotation. The exact way these commands are implemented depends on your car's hardware.

With rclcpp, you can also publish and receive messages using topic channels, allowing you to communicate with other nodes in the ROS 2 system.

It's important to note that the exact steps to take to control a real robot car depend on its hardware and the specific environment you're working in. I recommend that you read your car's documentation and hardware specifications to better understand how to control it with Raspberry Pi and rclcpp.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Fox cz but I'm afraid that Robotics Stack Exchange is an English Language site. I'll run your answer through a translator service this time, but please translate your answers in the future.

Comment: Is that you mean i still need library like WiringPi in order to control Raspberry Pi's GPIO and other hardware component? And the rclcpp will do things like calculating to get the desired behavior?